# How to install apps in phone which contains sqlite database in android

Tags: android

I want to install my app which contains regestration form whose username and password is stored im sqlite database. after copyiny .apk file my apps does not contains any database table for that work.
So my question is how to import this database in my app which is installed on android device it is working fine on emulator.

Comment: Updating your post with the stack trace will help.

Comment: does the app actually crash on the null pointer exception? If so, the password is not the problem... I have updated my answer

Comment: i have update my program then check it please

Comment: What is line Database.java:87?

Comment: storePassword1=db.getdata(unname);

Comment: change your query select password from login where  KEY_USERNAME=?

Comment: username instead of KEY_USERNAME

Comment: @nitesh any luck since last week?

Answer (score 2):

Have you initialized database class object

```
EditDatabase db=new EditDatabase(this);
```

onCreate or onResume activity?
if not then initialize it.

Comment: @nitesh chek.. password.equals(storedPassword1) condition. password or storePasword1 is not null

Comment: sry i cant understand what u want to say

Comment: that is not actually right - `a_not_null_variable.equals(null)` is valid, and should return `false` - very handy when making comparisons to constants. Its good practice to say MY_CONSTANT.equals(my_variable)  (i.e. yoda coding)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier yes you are right here.but if password is  null then it give null pointer error.

Comment: add condition  if(storedPassword1!=null) before your condition password.equals(storedPassword1)

Comment: @nvavadiya yes u r right about password not being null - however a previous comment seemed to suggest "password or storePasword1 is not null". And the comment right above this says to check "if(storedPassword1!=null)" but that is not going to help. . . I think you mean to check "if (password != null)"

Comment: @nitesh pls help us to help you - type the command 'adb logcat' into windows/terminal/command line, look for NullPointerException, and post the lines close to it.

Comment: its not possible to help you @nitesh until u give us log

Answer (score 1):

### Update from logcat output

Based on the logcat output, it shows that this is an unhandled exception. i.e. it happens outside the `try{} ... catch{}` block of the `onClick(View)` method.

This means that it is a problem in one of these 2 lines:

```
   unname = username1.getText().toString();
   storePassword1 = db.getdata(unname);
```

My feeling is that `username1` is null because it is not referenced in your layout XML file.

Here's how you should check - replace those 2 lines with these null checks:

```
    if (unname != null)
    {
        unname = username1.getText().toString();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("MyTag", "unname is null");

    }
    if (storePassword1 != null)
    {
        storePassword1 = db.getdata(unname);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("MyTag", "storePassword1 is null");
    }
    if (unname == null || storePassword1 == null)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Run the code again, check the logcat output again, and see if it tells you about the problem.

Also try not to use `System.out(String)` - rather use the `Log.d(String, String)` methods. These are more useful on Android.

---

### Original

Firstly, please provide a stack trace - it will show where the null pointer error happened.

For Android, the most useful way of doing that will be to use the `adb logcat` terminal command. This outputs the internal log of your Android device/emulator to the screen, so you can view what went wrong.

In your `catch{}` block, I would put the following line:

```
Log.d("MyTag", "Stack Trace of exception...", e);
```

This will output the text, and information about the error `e` to this log - I think it will include the stack trace.

Copy the lines starting with "MyTag" and paste them into your question.

---

Secondly, without the stack trace, confirm that these 3 variables are not `null` typically:

- username1
- db
- password (if the app actually crashed with the `NullPointerException` then this one is not the problem, because the exception would be handled by the `catch{}` block)

i.e. confirm that you have initialised all of them before the click event.

Comment: i am new to android sry i don't know abut sracktrace

Comment: @nitesh first check how to stack trace and then got for help in stack overflow.its difficult to help you without stack trace.